# Performing Prim's Algorithm using a class and a given starting point/node

Tags: python, class, graph, graph-algorithm

I have written a class Graph which takes a graph object and returns an adjacency list of the said graph object. I am using the graph_str from this class to construct a function which - given a point to start from - perform's prim's algorithm and outputs a parent's array as a result (a list of the parents of each node visited).

prim's algorithm explained - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cplfcGZmX7I

I have this working if the start point is assumed to be zero but I am unsure how to make it so that if the start point was a different number it would start from there instead.

The class I have is:

```
class Graph:    
def __init__(self, graph_str):
    self.graph_str = []
    graph_str = graph_str.splitlines()
    for i in graph_str:
        i = (i.split())
        self.graph_str.append(i)
    directed_helper = self.graph_str[0]
    directed_score = directed_helper[0]
    weighted_helper = self.graph_str[0]
    weighted_score = weighted_helper[1]
    self.weighted = weighted_score
    self.directed = directed_score
    self.graph_str.pop(0)
    if self.directed == ("D"):
        self.directed = True
    elif self.directed == ("U"):
        self.directed = False
    if self.weighted == ("W"):
        self.weighted = True
    elif self.weighted != ("W"):
        self.weighted = False
    if self.weighted == False:
        self.edge_number = graph_str[0]
        self.edge_number = list(self.edge_number)
        self.edge_number = self.edge_number[2]
        self.edge_number = int(self.edge_number)
        self.adjacency_list = [[] for _ in range(self.edge_number)]  
    elif self.weighted == True:
        self.edge_number = graph_str[0]
        self.edge_number = list(self.edge_number)
        self.edge_number = self.edge_number[4]
        self.edge_number = int(self.edge_number)
        self.adjacency_list = [[] for _ in range(self.edge_number)]             
    if self.weighted == False:
        if self.directed == True:
            for s in self.graph_str:
                self.first_element = s[0]
                self.first_element = int(self.first_element)
                self.second_element = s[1]
                self.second_element = int(self.second_element)
                self.adjacency_list[self.first_element].append((self.second_element, None))
        elif self.directed == False:
            for t in self.graph_str:
                self.first_element = t[0]
                self.first_element = int(self.first_element)
                self.second_element = t[1]
                self.second_element = int(self.second_element)
                self.adjacency_list[self.first_element].append((self.second_element, None))
                self.adjacency_list[self.second_element].append((self.first_element, None))
    elif self.weighted == True:
        if self.directed == True:
            for t in self.graph_str:
                self.first_element = t[0]
                self.first_element = int(self.first_element)
                self.second_element = t[1]
                self.second_element = int(self.second_element)
                self.third_element = t[2]
                self.third_element = int(self.third_element)
                self.adjacency_list[self.first_element].append((self.second_element, self.third_element))
        if self.directed == False:
            for t in self.graph_str:
                self.first_element = t[0]
                self.first_element = int(self.first_element)
                self.second_element = t[1]
                self.second_element = int(self.second_element)
                self.third_element = t[2]
                self.third_element = int(self.third_element)
                self.adjacency_list[self.first_element].append((self.second_element, self.third_element))
                self.adjacency_list[self.second_element].append((self.first_element, self.third_element))
    (self.adjacency_list)
```

and the function I have written thus far is:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from heapq import *

def prim( graph, start):
    conn = defaultdict( list )
    nodes = []
    parents_array = [None]
    for n1,n2,c in graph.graph_str:
        c = int(c)
        conn[ n1 ].append( (c, n1, n2) )
        conn[ n2 ].append( (c, n2, n1) )

    for i in graph.graph_str:
        a = i[0]
        nodes.append(a)


    mst = []
    used = set( nodes[ 0 ] )
    usable_edges = conn[ nodes[0] ][:]
    heapify( usable_edges )

    while usable_edges:
        cost, n1, n2 = heappop( usable_edges )
        if n2 not in used:
            used.add( n2 )
            mst.append( ( n1, n2, cost ) )

            for e in conn[ n2 ]:
                if e[ 2 ] not in used:
                    heappush( usable_edges, e )
    for i in mst:
        a = i[0]
        parents_array.append(a)

    return parents_array
```

Now for some examples. This code works for the following example, as the starting point is 0:

```
graph_str = """\
U W 7
0 1 5
0 2 7
0 3 12
1 2 9
2 3 4
1 4 7
2 4 4
2 5 3
3 5 7
4 5 2
4 6 5
5 6 2
"""

print(prim(Graph(graph_str), 0))
```

which outputs:

```
[None, 0, 0, 2, 5, 5, 2]
```

However I am yet get it to work with a starting point. For example:

```
graph_str = """\
U W 3
0 1 1
1 2 2
2 0 3
"""

print(prim(Graph(graph_str), 0))
print(prim(Graph(graph_str), 1))
print(prim(Graph(graph_str), 2))
```

Should output:

```
[None, 0, 1]
[1, None, 1]
[1, 2, None]
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I would advise you to post a minimal code example of just the `prim` function (which seems to be the one with a problem), showing what it receives, what it outputs, what what where you expecting it to output. You've included a lot of information in this question that apparently doesn't help to answer it. Best of luck :)